# Why it keeps giving "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:" when trying to install PyAudio using pip

Tags: python

I tried to update the pytube package but it still didn't work\

I used this commands to update the pytube package:
1.`pip3 install pytube`
2.`pip install pytube==10.8.5`\

this is the code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube.cli import on_progress
from tqdm import tqdm

link = input("Enter the URL: ")
video = YouTube(link, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
tqdm(video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path="D:/Charo/photos & videos"))
print("downloaded successfully")
```

and it keeps giving me this error "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\youtube downloader\yt v d.py", line 16, in <module>
    video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 308, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 213, in fmt_streams
    if "adaptive_fmts" in self.player_config_args:
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 187, in player_config_args
    self._player_config_args = self.vid_info
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 278, in vid_info
    return dict(parse_qsl(self.vid_info_raw))
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 108, in vid_info_raw
    self._vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 52, in get
    response = _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Eng.Emil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Hard to say what exactly causes the error, it's most likely not the package. It has to do the URL you entered, the website cannot be found (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). Can you hardcode the link and try again?

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you said to hardcode the link but it didn't work

Comment: Can you edit your answer and put the exact link you hardcoded in it? Have you tried other links as well or only one?